# Solving non-linear coupled ODE with constraint using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to use `NDSolve` in *Mathematica* to solve the following coupled ODEs from a paper I am trying to understand. I have the following 5 differential equations:

```
eqns = {x'[s] == Cos[θ[s]],
     y'[s] == Sin[θ[s]],
     θ''[s] == nx[s]*Sin[θ[s]] - ny[s] Cos[θ[s]], 
     nx'[s] == -(γ/r) Sin[θ[s]], 
     ny'[s] == (γ/r) Cos[θ[s]]};
```

And i have to solve them with 8 boundary conditions

```
bcs = {x[0] == 0,
     y[0] == 0, 
     θ[0] == 0, 
     x[D] == r Sin[β],
     θ'[D] == 0, 
     nx[D] == -γ Sin[β], 
     ny[D] == γ*Sin[β], 
     θ[D] == θY - β};
```

and a constraint:

```
constraint = r^2 (β - 1/2 Sin[2 β]) + 2 x[D] y[D] - 
     2 \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\),  \(0\), \(D\)]\(y[s] Cos[θ[s]] \[DifferentialD]s\)\);
```

I am trying to learn how to use shooting method which is what is apparently used in their work to solve this system. Can anyone suggest a way to do that or is there an alternate way of solving these kind of coupled non-linear systems with constraint? If you have a simpler example where shooting method is used with constraints, would also be helpful.

Comment: Googling `shooting method mathematica` returns nothing then, hmm .. ?!

Comment: @Sektor it did but i couldn't find one with a constraint such as this one, with an integral. And i am still a beginner in mathematica.

Comment: Do you know how to solve even a basic problem using the shooting method ?